# Segfault with realloc

Tags: c++, malloc, realloc

So I was using malloc in my program and then realloc within a method inside the program. After I called this method so many times I would get a "Segmentation fault (core dumped)".

Upon further inspection  I realized that for some reason when my pointer goes from 0x25d7d60 or 0x223fae0 (or any address represented by 7 digits (0xHHHHHHH) ) to 0x7f47d370a010 (with more than 7 digits) for example, a segfault is thrown from within the realloc call, realloc wont even return NULL.  I fixed this by simply using malloc and then memcpy instead.  However I am very confused at why this happened and wanted to see if any of the users of stackoverflow could shed some light on why this happened.

Thanks

Here is the relevant code:

```
 unsigned int* myArray;
 unsigned int num_ints;

 int main()
 {

   num_ints = 100; 
   if((myArray =(unsigned int*) malloc(sizeof(unsigned int)*(num_ints)*3))==NULL)
   {
    std::cout << "Malloc failed!" << std::endl;
    return false;
   }

   .
   .
   .

   //This called when n key is pressed (code left out)
   methodName();
 return true;
 }

 void methodName()
 {

 if((myArray =(unsigned int*) realloc(myArray,sizeof(unsigned int)*(num_ints*4)*3))==NULL)
 {
    std::cout << "Realloc failed!" << std::endl;
    exit(0);
 }

 }
```

Comment: Is it supposed to be C or C++??? Why is it tagged C and yet uses `std::cout`?

Comment: It is C++ I just tagged C because realloc is use in C and I don't use C++ functions at all really but was required to compile with g++.

Comment: @Matt: Don't use malloc, realloc or free in C++.

Comment: Voting to close as the problem proved to be not in the code posted.

Answer (score 5):

There's a good chance that, by calling "realloc within a method inside the program", you're actually loading it into a local variable which is then thrown away and your program continues to use the older pointer (which has now been freed).

We would need to see the code to be certain but, in my experience, that's the one of the major causes of allocation errors.

---

Based on what you've shown, there's nothing wrong with what you're doing. It's effectively the same as this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
int sz = 1000;
int *buffer = 0;
static int methodName (void) {
    if (sz == 100000)
        sz = 100;
    sz = sz * 10;
    if ((buffer = (int*)realloc (buffer, sz)) == 0) {
        std::cout << "Realloc error" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
int main(void) {
    int i;
    if ((buffer = (int*)malloc (sz)) == 0) {
        std::cout << "Alloc error" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        if (methodName() != 0)
            return 1;
    std::cout << "All okay" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

which works perfectly, doing ten million reallocations.

So the problems lies outside what you've shown us, perhaps a compiler bug (pretty unlikely if you're using a mainstream compiler) or memory corruption from elsewhere in your code.

Comment: I added code to the post.  Its not the actual code I used but extremely similar.  The code I used had the pointer as a global variable.

Comment: @Matt, I can see nothing wrong with the code you posted. You should either post the real code or at least code that exhibits the problem (preferably the smallest variant).

Comment: I agree.  And this is my actual code except I changed the myArray and num_ints variable names as well as the name of methodName.

Comment: @Matt: Then there's something wrong with your compiler or code outside of what you've shown us. I've run pretty much the exact same code reallocating memory to a random value between 1K and 100K over millions of iterations and it worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

If `realloc` changes the address of the array, then the `myarr` in the function scope (local) gets the new value, it does not change the `myarr` variable in the `main`

```
+---------+
| val1    |  = malloc (whatever);    <--------------------------+
+---------+                                                     |
|myarr    |                                                     |
+---------+                                                     |
|addr_main|                                                     |
+----+----+                                                     |
     |                                                          |
     |                                                          |
     |                                                (NO EFFECT on here)
(value of the myaddr 'val1')                                    |
(in main passed by value)                                       |
(to function)                                                   |
     |                                                          |
     +-------+                                                  |
             |                                                  |
             v                                                  |
methodname (myarr, someint)                                     |
             |                                                  |
             |                                                  |
             V                                                  |
        +---------+                                             |
        |  val1   |    = realloc (myarr, whatever)     ---------+
        +---------+    
        |myarr    |    if 'realloc' returns a new address
        +---------+    it will only overwrite 'val1' with some 'val2' 
        |addr_func|    in this LOCAL copy with address 'addr_func' 
        +---------+
             |
             |
             V
     (destroyed after function return)
```

Comment: Ok so that wasn't my actual code...I just did that on the fly. My actual code is on my school computer not this one. In my actual code myArray was a global variable

Comment: I know it should and it works until I hit the n key to get more memory like ten times and the address of the current memory was 0xHHHHHHH and is 0xHHHHHHHHHHHH for the first time befre it fails.  It works on my Mac fine and when I ssh into the Linux machine, but not when I'm physically on the Linux machine.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't change myArr in the main scope, realloc maybe return a new address, the old address is invalid.

Comment: Ok so that wasn't my actual code...I just did that on the fly. My actual code is on my school computer not this one. In my actual code myArray was a global variable

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `methodName` function is assigning the new pointer to it's local copy of myArray.

The quick fix is to make myArray a pointer to a pointer like so:

```
void methodName(unsigned int **myArray, unsigned int num_ints)
{
    if((*myArray = (unsigned int *)realloc((*myArray), sizeof(unsigned int)*(num_ints*4)*3)) == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Realloc failed!" << std::endl;
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

and then call it by passing the **address** of myArr:

```
methodName(&myArr, n_ints);
```

That way methodName gets the address of the memory of `main()`s myArr so that it can write into it.

As you can see though, having function parameters that output values can get a little hairy so I suggest instead `return`ing the new address:

```
unsigned int *methodName(unsigned int *myArray, unsigned int num_ints)
{
    return (unsigned int *)realloc(myArray, sizeof(unsigned int) * (num_ints * 4) *3); 
}
```

Then it's just a matter of overwriting `myArr` in `main`:

```
myArr = methodName(myArr, n_ints);
```

Comment: Ok so that wasn't my actual code...I just did that on the fly. My actual code is on my school computer not this one.  In my actual code myArray was a global variable

Comment: @Matt Those details are very important when posting questions here.  If you fix the code in the question I will update this answer.

Comment: I don't see any problems with the updated code. The problem might not be in the realloc.  Maybe someone else can spot it.

Comment: I don't see any problems either. Thats why I asked the question. It works until I hit the n key to get more memory like 10 times and the address of the current memory was 0xHHHHHHH and is 0xHHHHHHHHHHHH for the first time befre it fails. It works on my Mac fine and when I ssh into the Linux machine, but not when I'm physically on the Linux machine.