# Can someone find the mistake? Pure C realloc

Tags: c, malloc, scanf, realloc

I've got this code:

```
int main() {
   int i=0, n=0;
   char sep=NULL;
   double **aero=(double**)malloc(sizeof(double*));
   *aero=(double*)malloc(2*sizeof(double));
   printf("Zadejte souradnice:\n");
   while (1) {
      aero=(double**)realloc(aero,(n+1)*sizeof(double*));
      for (i=0; i<n+1; i++) {
          aero[i]=(double*)realloc(aero[i],2*sizeof(double));
      }
      if ((scanf("[%lf,%lf]%c",&aero[n][0],&aero[n][1],&sep))==3 && (sep=='\n' || sep==' '))      {
            n++;     
            continue;
      } else if (!feof(stdin)) {
            printf("Nespravny vstup.\n");
            freeArray2D(aero,n);
            return 0;
      }
      break;
   }
}
```

It works fine, but I can scanf coordinates (in format: [x,y]) only 19 times. Then it shows me Segmentation fault (core dumped). I use Linux compiler **gcc -Wall -pedantic main.c -lm** I have no idea, where is the problem. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Show us some example input, and the `freeArray2D` function.

Comment: Check this might help :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656799/segfault-with-realloc?rq=1

Comment: OT: `char sep = NULL;` shall be `char sep = '\0';` or `... = 0;`.

Answer (score 1):

In `aero[i]=(double*)realloc(aero[i],2*sizeof(double))`, if `i == n`, then `aero[i]` is uninitialzed. You should not call `realloc` on an uninitialized pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You never assign a fresh `malloc`ed buffer to `aero[1]`, but pass the garbage in there to `realloc`. Maybe you expected the `realloc` for `aero` to zero-initalize the memory?

Answer (score 1):

Your specific problem is that you `realloc` a pointer, `aero[n]`, that was never `malloc`ed in the first place (and is not necessarily NULL). That's a recipe for disaster.

You also have another issue though it's more an unnecessary-work problem than a fatal flaw. You are re-allocating every single `aero[]` variable in the loop when they're not actually changing in content *or* size. It appears to me that all you need to do in the loop is simply increase the size of the first level of memory `aero` and allocate memory for its new element:

```
while (1) {
    aero = realloc (aero, (n+1) * sizeof (double*));
    aero[n] = malloc (2 * sizeof (double));
    :
```

You'll notice I've removed the casting of the `malloc` return values. This casting is ill-advised in C as it can hide certain subtle errors. C is perfectly capable of converting the `void*` return values into any other pointer type *implicitly.*

And, of course, you should *never* assume that your memory allocations will work - I'd be checking the return values for `NULL` and exiting immediately if I found one.

The only other issue I had (other than my inability to read Czech of course) was the setting of the `char sep` to `NULL`. `NULL` is usually reserved for pointers rather than characters so it looks more sensible if you initialise it to `\0`.